# Should static classes have their first letter uppercased?

Tags: conventions, static-classes

Generally speaking, (for any *object-oriented* programming language) 
conventionally, should the first letter of a static class be uppercased?

As an example, in:

```
// Example of a static class in JavaScript ES6

class myStaticClass {
  static toUppercaseOrNotToUppercase() {
    return Stackoverflow.ask('Should static classes like this conventionally have their first letter uppercased?');
  }
}
```

Should the class be declared as `myStaticClass` or `MyStaticClass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to Microsoft  and best practices, Class Name should be in PascalCasingis  whether it static or not naming guidelines.